# Interlocked operations in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, concurrency

Are there interlocked(atomic) operations in iOS SDK?

I need interlocked increment\decrement and interlocked comparsion.

**UPDATE: ** My main problem is waiting for few NSThreads created by main thread(main thread mustn't work while other threads work).

I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `OSAtomicIncrement*`/`OSAtomicDecrement*` operations described in [Using Atomic Operations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW14).

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Language level atomics under C11 and C++11 are now available.

You can simply declare `_Atomic(int) a;`.

[A more detailed introduction](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1832575).

---

atomic operations and their documentation can be found in `libkern/OSAtomic.h`. an overview can be found under `man atomic`.

as well, you will likely find C11 and C++11 language/library support very soon.

Comment: C++11 support has been there for a while, including atomic operations.

Comment: @Marko thanks. the original answer is now 2 years old -- updated.

Comment: I don't think simply declaring with _Atomic() does enough. You also have to use the Atomic functions, e.g. to increment an _Atomic int, use atomic_fetch_add(&i, 1);

Answer (score -1):

Objective-C has the keyword *synchronized* for atomic operations.

```
@synchronized(object) {
    // ...
}
```

If you specify the attribute *atomic* in a property declaration, the setters and getters will be sythesized using these synchronized-blocks.

Also look at `NSLock` and `NSLocking` protocol.

Comment: last i read, @synchronized was *not* an atomic op; it was two full blown mutex locks plus exception handling.

Answer (score -2):

You can take a look at the properties (ObjectiveC 2.0 feature).

`@property int atomicProperty;`

There is in fact no 'atomic' specifier, as properties default to atomic. They can be set to 'nonatomic'.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html

You may be interested by `@synchronized` also. Or this part of the doc:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html

Comment: Is self.someProperty == 12345 a atomic operation if someProperty declared as atomic?

Comment: I think that's the purpose of the property yes. It adds some safeguards against concurrent accesses.