# Use std::atomic in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, std, atomic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interlocked operations in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862308/interlocked-operations-in-ios)

How can I use the std::atomic in iOS?

I get an error when
`#include <atomic>`

Or what should I include?
Or is there any alternative?

Thanks.

EDIT:
The usage is in the .cpp file, but in the iOS project.

Comment: not imo, he wants to use the std => c++ in objc

Comment: Sorry I've edited my question. I'm writing c++ in an iOS project. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compile your .m files as objc++ - easiest way: rename them to .mm

also link against libstdc++ under your project settings > build phases > link with frameworks